# drop table com tabela temporária dando erro

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

```
qryCIDtemp.SQL.Text := 'drop table if exists #tempCID';  //apaga a tabelas temporária
```

O Delphi me retorna a seguinte mensagem em tempo de execução:

> ```
> Invalid use of keyword
> Token: if
> Line Number: 1.
> ```

Se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito grata.

EDIT:
Teste com a sugestão da resposta abaixo:
Fiz como sugeriu:

```
 qryCIDtemp.SQL.Text := 'if object_id('#tempCID','U') Is not null drop table #tempCID'; //apaga a tabelas temporária
```

e também não funcionou. Agora o erro é de compilação. o delphi me retorna:

> Missing operator or semicolon. Statement expected, but expression of
>   type 'String' found.

Tem outra ideia?

Comment: Tente: `IF OBJECT_ID('#tempCID') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempCID`

Comment: As mensagens de erro não foram retornadas pelo SQL Server mas sim pelo Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar o comando:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#tempCID') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempCID
```

Porém, para que isto funcione no Delphi, você precisa utilizar a seguinte String, escapando as aspas simples com outra aspa simples `'`:

```
 qryCIDtemp.SQL.Text := 'IF OBJECT_ID(''#tempCID'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempCID';
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa sintaxe `if exists` pode não funcionar no `SQL-Server`, é uma sintaxe nova a partir do **SQL SERVER 2016**, você pode fazer assim:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#tempCID', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempCID
```

`OBJECT_ID` é uma função que torna o id de um objeto, e caso seu retorno seja `null`, o objeto (tabela no caso) não existe, por isso o `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: também não funcionou.

Comment: retorna algum erro? Como você está executando o comando? não aparece essa parte no seu código

Comment: Seu problema deve ser as aspas, tem que colocar duplas aspas assim: `'IF OBJECT_ID(''#tempCID'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempCID'`

Answer (score 0):

Na função OBJECT_ID, para tabelas temporárias é necessário sempre citar o nome do banco de dados tempDB:

```
-- código #1
IF Object_ID(N'tempDB..#tempCID', N'U') is not null
  DROP TABLE #tempCID;
```

Ao encapsular o comando acima no programa em Delphi fique atenta aos apóstrofos:

```
qryCIDtemp.SQL.Text := 'IF Object_ID(N''tempDB..#tempCID'', N''U'') is not null DROP TABLE #tempCID';
```